# How to identify client of character driver

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to write a linux character driver which implements a "tagged MUX" functionality writing to a special hardware link. But I'm having trouble with some key concepts.

Users `open` the device and use an `ioctl` to set an ID which is associated with their data type. From there, any data written to the respective file descriptors are prefixed by the ID, formatted a appropriately for the hardware link, and sent on the link.

Multiple users could be in the same user-space process or across multiple processes. eg, a single process example:

```
int alarmFd = open("/dev/tagmux", O_WRONLY);
ioctl(alarmFd, SET_ID, 123);

int dataFd = open("/dev/tagmux", O_WRONLY);
ioctl(dataFd, SET_ID, 456);

void onAlarm()
{
  data = // specific binary data about the alarm...
  write(alarmFd, data, dataLen);
}

void onMeas()
{
  data = // specific binary data about the alarm...
  write(alarmFd, data, dataLen);
}
```

So in the rough driver code below, I'm not sure how to differentiate between the different clients. `hwSetFrameId` must be set to "123" for data written to `alarmFd` and to "456" for data written to `dataFd`.

How could I do that?

```
const struct file_operations muxFops =
{
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = muxOpen,
    .read = NULL,
    .write = muxWrite,
    .release = muxRelease,
    .unlocked_ioctl = muxIoctl
};

void muxOpen(struct inode *pInode, struct file *pFile)
{
  // remember this client in a list
}

static long muxIoctl(struct file *filep, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    uint32_t __user *userPtr = (uint32_t __user *) arg;

    switch (cmd)
    {
    case MUX_SET_ID:
        result = get_user(tagValue, userPtr);
        clientId = // get client Id here
        tagList[clientId] = tagValue;
    }
}

static ssize_t
muxWrite(struct file *file, const char  __user *buf, size_t nBytes, loff_t *ppos)
{
    clientId = // getClient Id here
    tagValue = tagList[clientId];
    hwSetFrameId(tagValue);
    hwSetFrameData(buf, nBytes);
    hwTriggerTx();
}
```

Comment: Each opening of the device has its own entry in the file table. You should be able to store the per-client state there, similar to the way regular files store the file position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> remember this client in a list

You have `file->private_data`. See https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html#implementation-of-operations .